# Javascript animations not working properly when zooming in and out

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation

I have created an animation in javascript that uses setTimeout to change various element's css properties by timing but I just noticed when zooming in and out, the timeout functions continues but the animation stops / slows down resulting to elements stacking together then it rushes all the animations to finish after you stop the zooming (something like when the tab is inactive, the animation seems to stop and resume when you get back to the tab where the animation is previously running) though it's not that much of an issue as it goes back to it's normal flow when you stop the zooming, it is just irritating.

Is that a normal thing? Or is there something in my codes that I needed to fix?

EDIT: Here is a sample code

```
    var scaleRegEx = new RegExp(/scale\([\s\S]+?\)/i);

    function moveThis(el, xpos, ypos){
        el.style.left = xpos + 'px';
        el.style.top = ypos + 'px';
    }

    function scaleThis(el, xscale, yscale){
        if (scaleRegEx.test(el.style.transform) === false){
            el.style.transform += " scale(" + xscale + "," + yscale + ")";
        } else {
            el.style.transform = el.style.transform.replace(
                scaleRegEx, "scale(" + xscale + "," + yscale + ")"
            );
        }
    }

    function setClip(el, x, y, width, height){
        el.style.clip = "rect(" + y + "px," + (x+width) + "px," + (y+height) + "px," + x + "px)";
    }

    var images = new Array(
        "assets/bg.png",
        "assets/box-open.png",
        "assets/box-closed.png",
        "assets/link.png",
        "assets/cursor.png",
        "assets/product-big.png",
        "assets/text1.png",
        "assets/text2.png",
        "assets/text3.png",
        "assets/logo.png",
        "assets/box-openback.png"
    );

    var loadedImage = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i <= images.length - 1; i++) {
        imageObj = new Image();
        imageObj.src = images[i];
        imageObj.addEventListener("load", iLoad, false)
    }

    function iLoad() {
        loadedImage++;
        if (images.length == loadedImage) {

            bg.style.background         = "url('" + images[0]  + "') no-repeat";
            boxOpen.style.background    = "url('" + images[1]  + "') no-repeat";
            boxClosed.style.background  = "url('" + images[2]  + "') no-repeat";
            link.style.background       = "url('" + images[3]  + "') no-repeat";
            cursorIcon.style.background = "url('" + images[4]  + "') no-repeat";
            productBig.style.background = "url('" + images[5]  + "') no-repeat";
            text1.style.background      = "url('" + images[6]  + "') no-repeat";
            text2.style.background      = "url('" + images[7]  + "') no-repeat";
            text3.style.background      = "url('" + images[8]  + "') no-repeat";
            logo.style.background       = "url('" + images[9]  + "') no-repeat";
            boxBack.style.background    = "url('" + images[10] + "') no-repeat";

            setClip(productBig, 0, 0, 615, 631);
            setClip(text2, 0, 0, 768, 90);

            setTimeout(startScene1, 2000);
        }
    }

    // zoom out the product
    function startScene1(){
        text1.style.opacity = 0;

        //fade out big product
        scaleThis(productBig, 0.13, 0.13);
        moveThis(productBig, 235, -45);

        scaleThis(boxOpen, 1.0, 1.0);
        moveThis(boxOpen, 0, 0);

        scaleThis(boxBack, 1.0, 1.0);
        moveThis(boxBack, 0, 0);

        // put the product inside box
        setTimeout(function(){
            productBig.className += " productTransition";
            productBig.style.top = "30px";
            setClip(productBig, 0, 0, 615, 0);
        }, 3000);

        // show text 2
        setTimeout(function(){
            text2.style.opacity = 1;
        }, 1000);

        // dispose text2
        setTimeout(function(){
            text2.style.left = "-728px";
        }, 4000);
    }
```

Comment: Oh yes, sorry about that. Wait gonna edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

what you are experiencing is the browser has to pause the rendering of animations in order to render the zoom but unfortunately is not pausing the timeout. What you should do rather than just simply relying on your timeout to say it is time for the next animation to start you should check to ensure the previous animation has completed or is at a certain progress point. Such as you have one animation that fades an element out followed by another that begins its fade in when the first element is faded out. Before inititating the second animation check that animatedElement1.style.opacity==0;if not set another timeout or even loop until opacity==0

Comment: I see.. so it is mostly the browser's fault and that I needed to adjust my code  a bit to compensate that. Thanks for the info. I'm gonna look more into that issue.

Comment: Yes certain browser events can cause the animations to get off track. some browsers will compensate and skip parts of the animation if it detects it is behind but not all. It is generally good practice however to always verify the animation was complete before executing another one that is dependent on the first ones completion. There is a million and 1 things that could make the first animation fail and you will want to know if this happened before launching the second animation.